# Getting the Asana ID of users who added hearts in comments

Tags: asana

I would like to know how to get the IDs of users who added a heart in a comment.  I am able to get the heart IDs, but it's not useful if I don't know the user who added that heart.

Currently I'm using this API call:

```
$t = $asana->getTaskStories('14575329695751', array("opt_fields"=>"hearts"));
```

Output:

```
{"data":[{"id":14575329695752},{"id":14575329695753},{"id":14575329695754},{"id":14583810864882},{"id":14605823660851},{"id":14605823660853,"hearts":[]},{"id":14631534715087,"hearts":[]},{"id":14704515309441,**"hearts":[{"id":14708668721707},{"id":14712262220995}]}**,{"id":14704539740313,"hearts":[]}]}
```

I get the story ID and the heart ID, but I am unable to get the user ID / name who added those hearts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hearts themselves have properties of their own you can include with `opt_fields`. For example, if you included `opt_fields=hearts.user.name` it will show the user (with name and ID). Hearts have the properties `user`, `created_at`, and `target`.

Documentation for hearts will be added to the [public docs](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/) soon, but hopefully that helps in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
That's just what I needed!